# Background cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android

```
private void initializeall() {
    //using phn er display size janar jonno
    WindowManager windowManager=(WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display defaultDisplay=windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

    //value near jonno point class e nea holo, jar measurment holo x r y
    Point displaydimennsion=new Point();
    defaultDisplay.getSize(displaydimennsion);//displaydimension e display er size ta save hoye gelo
    displayx=displaydimennsion.x;
    displayy=displaydimennsion.y;

    //setting background
    backgroundBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.background);//resource==context er resource
}
```

Here background is not assigned. I have checked the whole code line by line with its resource, but I didn't get anything mismatch or wrong with that. I am using Windows 7, Java compiler, JDK, Android tool kit and it is a Java code.

Comment: a little snippet, no error, no stacktrace, no explanation, and no clues on what you tried... please give us some  details and/or start by something easiest if it's your first time on Android...

Answer (score 0):

Your generated `R.drawable` class does not have a `background` field.

Some possibilities:

- You don't have a `background` file in one of your `res/drawable` folders
- There was some error compiling your resources and the generated `R` was not updated
- You imported the wrong `R` i.e. platform `android.R` instead of `your.package.R`.